# AlamofireImage testing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofireimage

How can i check that AlamofireImage Caching is working?

While i'm running the app i can see caching is working - it reuses cached images instead of downloading them when possible (cache is available)

But when i close the app or re run the code it does not reusing caches - they do not exists - so it is downloading the images again for every run.

How can i be sure that the caching will work for the user even after he close the app and re-open it?

i used NSLog to pring to system log.

```
func loadImage() {
        if let image = photosManager.cachedImage(for: photo.url) {
            NSLog("Image Cache Found")
            populate(with: image)
            return
        }
        NSLog("Image Cache NOT Found")
        downloadImage()
    }
```

i run the app from simulator
and i see the same behaviour - it prints "Image Cache NOT Found" every time i'm terminating the app (Double-click the Home button - and swipe up the app)

Thanks.